# How can I store my data in mongodb without returning my data within an object?

Tags: json, mongodb, cypress

I am using cypress to run my tests and I am using cypress mongo-db plugin to get my data into mongodb, here is my code:

```
const data = require('../../fixtures/data.json')
```

// this is importing the data

```
cy.insertOne( {data},collection: "contract_data", database: "my_db" })
```

// cy.insertOne inserts the data, collection is the name of the folder, database is the name of the db.

This is my output

```
id(UUID) object {   id: UUID   name: string }
```

How can I store my data without the object{} and just the data itself?

I am unclear whether this is something related to the way I am importing the file or something which I should be configuring on mongoDB.

Comment: You do not need to use returned object if you don't need the id of the inserted document.

Comment: The object is only appears when it reaches the database which is what I'm trying to remove but I'm not sure how.

Comment: I am not getting the problem you are having then. Could you please more specific?

Comment: Have you tried removing brackets around data ?

Comment: that seemed to have worked! Thank you!!